# Django include tag is displayed in browser not the actual include

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to seperate a navbar in an extra file and import/include it into my base template.

The problem is {% include 'sidebar.html %} is just displayed in the browser and does not work as I think it would...

**Folder structur**

```
|-project
  |-static
    |-css
    |-js
  |-templates
    |-base.html
    |-sidebar.html
  |- static
  |- ...
|-app0
  |-templates
    |-home.html
  |-...
|-manage.py
```

**src/project/templates/base.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    {% load static %}

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>Profile</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
    
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

**src/project/templates/sidebar.html**

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="/"> Home</a>
  <h3>Headline0</h3>
  <a href="/test0">Test0</a>
  <h3>Headline 1</h3>
  <a href="/test1">Test1</a>
</div>
```

**src/app0/templates/home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
   Hi <span id="name"></span>
   <div id="counter"></div>
   <script src="{% static 'js/index.js' %}" charset="UTF-8"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**Browser output:**

[image: brave browser (chrome) output]

Does have anyone some ideas about it?

**Answer**
The comment of is right. Thank you for that and sorry for the dump question.
Ivan Starostin

Comment: your home.html and base,sidebar files are on different location.

Comment: render looks like there is an extra symbol between opening { and % which breaks template syntax

Comment: Use `{% endblock content %}` as closing tag instead of `{% endblock %}` in ***src/app0/templates/home.html*** & don't put spaces in between `{` & `%` it should be without spaces like this `{%`